# Default language in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am discovering currently Visual Studio 2010. I have no experience whatsoever with Visual Basic. I see that Visual Studio supports several languages, that [C# is easier than C++ for newbies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370141/1458491), but I still don't know what is the default language in that program.

In my first test application, I can insert buttons and many other things on a form. Looking at the code gives something like that:

```
Private Sub Beenden_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Beenden.Click 
End Sub
```

This looks to me like VBA, but I never decided what language I want to use. Is that Visual Basic? Or VB.NET then?

Thanks for clarifying all this!

Comment: What you have shown there is VB.NET, but there is no "default" language for Visual Studio... it's down to the individual languages that have been installed, and which one you choose when you create a new project

Comment: @freefaller - There are defaults, if you consider the Express editions.

Comment: @Oded - I was not aware of that, but the OP does say "Visual Studio 2010"... nothing about Express editions.  But I made it a comment rather than an answer, because I wasn't 100% sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language is most probabaly VB.NET.

Visual Studio does not have a "default language".

What language you use depends on the project you have created - there are templates for C#, VB.NET and C++ in the default installation, but you can add many other templates and languages.

The above applies to the non-free versions of Visual Studio (Pro, Ultimate etc...).

The [Express Editions](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) are language specific (you can download and run these side-by-side).